# Syndicate email studio content

Tags: ampscript, content-builder, landing-page, email-studio, microsites

I'm trying to create a microsite that uses dynamic content created in the content builder to display.

If you imagine I have 12 posts, 4 on topic x, 4 on topic y, 4 on topic z+y, I would like to be able to create this content in the content builder and **tag it**, I'd then like to have a feed (RSS) that dynamically pulls tagged-content, and to display that content on pages in the microsite.  That would (I think) also let me create emails using dynamic content snippets (by ingesting the rss). I don't care about the content being dynamic for different viewers (which is how it's used in some of the help), it's dynamic as in the feeds update when I create and tag new content.

I know I can do this using an external RSS. I cannot work out if within the salesforce suite I can create content to be *externally* syndicated rather than ingested.  The issues are:

- tagging content
- fetching a feed for salesforce content
- displaying that feed (I think I know how to do this/know where to look, and know it will likely involve AmpScript)

The help pages are unfortunately not helping (I've checked syndication, tags, dynamic content, and looked for guidance on ampscript but can't see anything).

Any help much appreciated

Comment: And just for context, the reason I'm not just doing this externally is because I'm trying to stick to tools my institution supports (although, support is limited to simple uses), and our standard website setup bizarrely won't let me do this either...

Comment: Content Builder's not the best tool for this. You have tags that you can associate with content. Manage tags up in Setup -> Platform Tools -> Feature Settings -> Tags. You have the Content Builder API that you can use to retrieve assets using a query (tags = x). You have SSJS that you can use to make REST calls to the API and you have Cloud Pages that you can use to run SSJS and present data in RSS format publicly. Wordpress would be easier, though. For performance, I'd recommend running your SSJS in an Automation to refresh feed data periodically. CloudPage to just present the data.